# Subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^3$ homeomorphic to quotient spaces

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

For the following three questions:

Construct subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^3$ homeomorphic to the following quotient spaces:
a) $\mathbb{R}^2/\mathbb{D}^2$, where $\mathbb{D}^2$ is the closed unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^2$
b) $\mathbb{R}^2/\mathbb{S}^1$, and
c) $\mathbb{R}^2/(\mathbb{R}^2 - \mathbb{B}^2)$, where $\mathbb{B}^2$ is the open unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^2$

I would like to know for the subspaces for the three questions, the answer for (a), is it the unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^3$. 
For (b), it would also be the unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^3$. 
I am not sure what (c) is supposed to be.  If anyone can tell me also, it would be much appreciated.  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not quite sure with your answers.

(a) $\Bbb R^2 / \Bbb D^2$ looks like $\Bbb R^2$ to me

Consider the map $$(x,y,0) \mapsto ((\sqrt{x^2+y^2}-1)x,(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}-1)y,1) \text{ if } x^2+y^2\geq 1 \\
               $$
and map $\Bbb D^2$ to $(0,0,1)$.

Use Gluing lemma to obtain the quotient map and  then use Fundamental Theorem of Quotient Topology to conclude!

(b) $\Bbb R^2/S^1$ looks like $\Bbb R^2 \lor S^2$

Consider the map $$(x,y,0) \mapsto ((\sqrt{x^2+y^2}-1)x,(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}-1)y,1) \text{ if } x^2+y^2\geq 1 \\
               $$

For $\Bbb D^2$, consider the boundary identification map  i.e. $q: \Bbb D^2  \to S^2 $ (that identifies the boundary  $\partial \Bbb D^2 =S^1$ to a point ) and glue these two maps suitably i.e. make $q(S^1)=(0,0,1)$ . This will give a quotient map and then use Fundamental Theorem of Quotient Topology to conclude!

(c)$\Bbb R^2/(\Bbb R^2 -\Bbb B^2) $ looks like $S^2$

For $\Bbb D^2$, consider the boundary identification map  i.e.  $q: \Bbb D^2 \to S^2 $ ( that identifies the boundary $\partial \Bbb D^2=S^1$  to a point ) and simply map $\Bbb R^2- \Bbb B^2$ to the point where $q$ maps $S^1$ , you have your quotient map (again by gluing lemma) and then use Fundamental Theorem of Quotient Topology to conclude!

After these identifications I guess it is trivial to just give some coordinates and make a concrete subspace.

Comment: can I ask how you came up with the map $$(x,y,0) \mapsto ((\sqrt{x^2+y^2}-1)x,(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}-1)y,1) \text{ if } x^2+y^2\geq 1 \\ $?

Comment: (1) I have to scale things and (2) Have to identify $S^1$ somehow

Comment: can I ask, when you say scale things, can you elaborate a bit more.  Also, for parts (b) and (c), why would I need to consider what to do with $\mathbb{D}^2$?  Thank you.

Comment: Visualize how your quotienting, that should give all the answers..

Comment: thank you, much appreciated it.

Answer (score 0):

(a) $\mathbb{R}^2 \times \{0\}$
(b) $\{ (0,0), (x,y) : 0 < xy \}\times\{0\}$
(c) $S^2$

Comment: sorry if my request for clarification is tersely worded.  I was having trouble picturing the three spaces.  In the case of (a), am i suppose to picture the entire $\mathbb{D}^2$ as an one element set and leave everything surrounding the unit disk as it is.  Also, for (b), if i treat the circle as it is.  Don't I just get three sets, the plane minus the boundary of the unit circle, the unit circle as an one element set, and the interior of the circle as one set.